# PL/SQL Calling a function to a procedure

Tags: plsql

Previously,I asked about creating a function that returns total amount of salaries from a parameter city.
I chose Dallas for instance.Tables are EMP and DEPT:
 You can find them below

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_O5AEB2HE08PYEPTGCFLZU9YCV.html

Mistakenly I wrote in my language instead of english at the end of it but I corrected it.

Now I need to create a procedure which lists ascending the employees and their salaries from another parameter city.After listing them I need to call the function for the second city.Problem is I get an error for the 'loop' from the  procedure and i got no idea why.

```
set serveroutput on;
 create or replace function show_sal (local dept.loc%type) return number as
      vval number;
    begin
      select sum(emp.sal)
        into vval
        from emp inner join dept on dept.deptno = emp.deptno
        where upper(dept.loc) = upper(local);
     return vval;
   end;
   /
 begin
      dbms_output.put_line('Total sum of salaries from DALLAS = ' || show_sal('DALLAS'));
    end;
    /

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE show_employees(v_loc dept.loc%TYPE) AS

CURSOR c IS
SELECT ename,sal
 FROM emp INNER JOIN dept ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno
 WHERE UPPER(loc)=UPPER(v_loc)
 ORDER BY ename ASC;

 v_name VARCHAR2;
v_salaries emp.sal%TYPE;

BEGIN
OPEN c
LOOP
FETCH c INTO v_name,v_salaries;
EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name||'  '|| v_salaries);
END LOOP;
CLOSE c;
END;
/
EXECUTE show_employees('CHICAGO');

BEGIN
show_sal('CHICAGO');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set serveroutput on;
 create or replace function show_sal (local dept.loc%type) return number as
      vval number;
    begin
      select sum(emp.sal)
        into vval
        from emp inner join dept on dept.deptno = emp.deptno
        where upper(dept.loc) = upper(local);
     return vval;
   end;
   /
 begin
      dbms_output.put_line('Total sum of salaries from DALLAS = ' || show_sal('DALLAS'));
    end;
    /

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE show_employees(v_loc dept.loc%TYPE) AS
 CURSOR C is SELECT ename,sal
 FROM emp,dept
 WHERE emp.deptno=dept.deptno AND UPPER(loc)=UPPER(v_loc)
 ORDER BY ename ASC;

 v_nume emp.ename%TYPE;
v_salariu emp.sal%TYPE;
v_tot emp.sal%TYPE;


BEGIN
v_tot:=show_sal('CHICAGO');
dbms_output.put_line('nume   salar                             total: '||v_tot);
OPEN C;
LOOP
FETCH C INTO v_nume,v_salariu;
EXIT WHEN C%NOTFOUND;
dbms_output.put_line(v_nume||'    '||v_salariu);
END LOOP;
CLOSE C;
END;
/
EXECUTE show_employees('CHICAGO');
```

Comment: This works.Had to put the call of the function in the body of the procedure by adding an aditional variable to it so it can work.

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot the semicolon after `OPEN c`.

And here is how to do the same with an implicit cursor, which is much easier to deal with in my opinion:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE show_employees(v_loc dept.loc%TYPE) AS
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN
  (
    SELECT ename, sal
    FROM emp
    WHERE deptno IN (SELECT deptno FROM dept WHERE UPPER(loc) = UPPER(v_loc))
    ORDER BY ename
  ) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.ename || '  ' || rec.sal);
  END LOOP;
END show_employees;
```

Comment: I understand but still I need to call that function at the end.Im a beginner and if my proffessor would see this he'll know I "cheated it". I still get errors after putting dat semicolon.

Comment: Your code was fine. Just put in the missing semicolon and it should work. What error are you getting? I have just shown you that you could also write the procedure with `FOR <my record name> IN (<my query>) LOOP ... END LOOP;`, which makes the task easier, as you don't have to declare a cursor, open it, loop through it, check for the cursor end and close the cursor. What I am showing is called an implicit cursor, because all this fetching is done for you behind the scenes. It's just to show you there exists a more convenient way. Maybe your prof will show you this later.

Comment: Just never say "I am getting an error", but show us the error message instead. Don't have us guess.

Answer (score 0):

Errors i get:

Function SHOW_SAL compiled

Total sum of salaries from DALLAS = 10875

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Procedure SHOW_EMPLOYEES compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR

---

9/9       PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)
Errors: check compiler log

Error starting at line : 40 in command -
BEGIN show_employees('CHICAGO'); END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 61:
PLS-00905: object HR.SHOW_EMPLOYEES is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 61:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Error starting at line : 42 in command -
BEGIN
show_sal('CHICAGO');
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00221: 'SHOW_SAL' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: It shows you the line and the problem. The 9th line in the procedure is: `v_name VARCHAR2;`. The error message is `String length constraints must be ...`. This means you must define the maximum string length, e.g. `v_name VARCHAR2(100);`. The rest may be subsequent errors.

Comment: Anyway. This is not an answer, so you should delete it. If you want to add details to your request, click the edit link under the request in order to do so.